# Is there a sense in which the differential of a smooth map between manifolds is a particular case of the pushforward of a vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, pushforward

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)) seems to suggest that the two concepts are somehow related but I don't see exactly how the pushforward of a vector field is a generalization of the differential of a map.

To clarify: if $\varphi: M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth map between smooth manifolds, the differential/pushforward of $\varphi$ at $x$ is a linear map $$d \varphi_x : T_x M \rightarrow T_{\varphi(x)} N$$ whose exact definition depends on the definition one uses for tangent vectors (but all of them are equivalent). If tangent vectors are defined as [derivations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) acting on smooth real-valued functions, then the pushforward is given by

$$d \varphi_x (X)(f) = X (f \circ \varphi)$$

for an arbitrary function $ f\in C^{\infty }(N)$ and an arbitrary derivation $X\in T_{x}M$ at point $x\in M$.  By definition, the pushforward of
$X$ is in $ T_{\varphi (x)}N$ and therefore itself is a derivation,
$ d\varphi _{x}(X):C^{\infty }(N)\to \mathbb {R} $.

On the other hand, each smooth vector field $ X:M\rightarrow TM$ on a manifold $M$ may be regarded as a differential operator acting on smooth functions $f(p)$ (where $p\in M$ and $f$ of class $C^{\infty }(M))$ when we define
$X(f)$ to be another function whose value at a point
$p$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction $X(p)$. In this way, each smooth vector field $X$ becomes a derivation on $C^{\infty}(M)$. Furthermore, any derivation on $C^{\infty}(M)$ arises from a unique smooth vector field $X$.

What I was thinking is, if we consider that the derivations in the above definition of the differential are vector fields, could it be considered a special case of the pushforward of a vector field (in the case in which it can be well defined as a vector field on $N$)? (I won’t reproduce the definition of pushforward here because it’s very long, but you can find it on the Wikipedia article…)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> It might be desirable to reword so that the question body is self-contained. <> If $f:M \to N$ is a smooth map of manifolds and $X$ is a vector field on $M$, I think of the differential $df:TM \to TN$ as a mapping between the tangent bundles, while the pushforward $f_*X$ is a section of the pullback bundle $f^*TN$ over $M$. They're related because the fibre of $f^*TN$ over $x$ is naturally identified with $T_{f(x)}N$, but it seems a small stretch to say one construction "generalizes" the other. If you can clarify your intent, that would be nice.

Comment: The pushforward of a tangent vector *is* the differential of a map. In particular, given a smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ of manifolds, the differential of $f$ at point $p \in M$ is a linear map $df_p: T_pM \rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$. Given any tangent vector $v \in T_pM$, the pushforward of $v$ is defined to be $f_*v = df_p(v)$. It's actually not always a good idea to think about the pushforward of a vector field, because you don't get a vector field on $N$. Instead, you get a section of the the pullback bundle $f^*T_*N$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you. I tried to clarify my question adding an edit.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for your answer. What I’m trying to understand is, doesn’t the fact they’re both called “pushforward” imply both concepts are somehow related? I understand that the pushforward of a vector field isn’t always a vector field, I’m referring to the particular case in which it is.

Comment: Sorry. I should have read your question more carefully. Now that I have, I confess I don't understand your question. What I can say is the following: The definition of the pushforward of a vector field $X$ on $M$ is indeed just whatever you get by pushing forward each $X(p)$. And, if $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then the pushforward of $X$ does define a vector field $Y$ on $N$, given by $Y(q) = df_{f^{-1}(q)}(X(f^{-1}(q)))$.

Comment: @Deane Thank you. I think my confusion is cleared now.